# Two way data binding from controller to directive and then further directive to nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

**Our Post data Array:
Profile Pic
Name
Post Content
Likes
Comments**

Actually, we've a data array(Suppose 10 posts) bound from a controller with a directive(Post), which showing the post correctly. Then further the directive(Post) attached with a child directive(User Info containing the name, pic etc). Both are two-way data bindings from the controller to directive and directive to child directive. When we pass suppose N posts first time, directives render properly, but as we add some new post(Mean unshift the array) to data in controller, it renders correctly in first directive(Post) but the new change incorrectly(Second directive shows the data from old post at 0 index rather of new 0 index) moves to the second directive.

Please help me in this regards.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?